# login Issue in android

Tags: android, json, webserver

I have a login page, it works fine when i put correct username and password but for login failure its not working how to handle this. 
In android i don't have any idea if any one can provide code please

**here is my code** :

```
package com.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;

public class Login extends Activity {   
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String URL ="http:.asmx?op=LoginRequest";       

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
    //private String login="";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    ImageButton login_button,sign_button;
    TextView m,p,f,email,password,forgot_password;
    EditText emailid,epassword;
    AlertDialog authProgressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
        forgot_password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgot);

        Context context = email.getContext();  
        Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"arial.ttf");         
        email.setTypeface(font);

        Context con = password.getContext();  
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(con.getAssets(),"arial.ttf");
        password.setTypeface(face);

        Context con1 = forgot_password.getContext();  
        Typeface face1=Typeface.createFromAsset(con1.getAssets(),"arial.ttf");         
        forgot_password.setTypeface(face1);

//      new theTask().execute();

        login_button=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.login);
        sign_button=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.signup);

        login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username,password;
                emailid =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edemail);
                epassword =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edpassword);

                username = emailid.getText().toString();
                password = epassword.getText().toString();


                showDialog(0);


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
                String qry="{\"General\":"+"{\"type\": \"Request\","+"\"application\": \"Mmmmm\","+"\"appver\": \"1.0.0\","+"\"phoneDeviceID\": \"123456789\","+"\"deviceType\": \"Android\","+"\"deviceOSVersion\": \"3.0\"},"+"\"Login\":"+"{\"emailID\":"+"\""+username+"\","+"\"password\":"+"\""+password+"\""+"}"+"}";
                Log.i("Input",qry);

                request.addProperty("JSONRequestString",qry);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                envelope.bodyOut=request;
                envelope.encodingStyle=SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2001;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransPort= new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

                try
                {
                    try {
                        androidHttpTransPort.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SoapPrimitive rest=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    Log.i("output","Result"+rest );
                    //   SoapObject var = (SoapObject)rest.getProperty(0);

                    String conv=rest.toString();
                    JSONObject js=new JSONObject(conv);

                    String login = js.getString("Login");
                    JSONObject err=new JSONObject(login);

                    String messcode=js.getString("HomePageFooterNewUpdates");
                    JSONObject code=new JSONObject(messcode);

                    int GetMessageCode=code.getInt("noOfMail");
                    Log.i("message code ","is " +GetMessageCode);
                    //      String errc=err.getString("errorMsg");
                    //      Log.i("err",errc);
                    int ResponseForLogin=err.getInt("errorCode");
                            Log.i("Response ","is "+ResponseForLogin);  

                    if(ResponseForLogin==000){
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                         // prepare the dialog box
               /*       ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

                        // make the progress bar Cancelable
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);

                        // set a message text
                        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");

                        // show it
                        dialog.show();*/

                        Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,Home.class);
                        i.putExtra("messcode", GetMessageCode);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Emailid or Password...Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SoapFault e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



        }    );

        sign_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, Signup.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you talking about login activity of your application? If yes, you can just make a Toast that inform user about wrong login/password

Comment: no max below u can check what am asking

Comment: @user701735 We need to see the code you are using to handle logins.  Please edit your question to include this code.

Comment: okie.... i wil edit my question..

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you few hints , try to take help from this.

```
ImageButton login=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Login);
EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailText);
EditText   editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);

login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if((editText1.getText()+" ").trim().equals("") || editText1.getText() == null || (editText2.getText()+" ").trim().equals("") || editText2.getText() == null ){

                    //show error message here

                }
                else{

                    //perrform your action here 
                    //either start a new activity or do something else

                }

            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: dinesh thats not my problem my problem is when i clik on login button username and password is getting verified in backend from web server and it throws login response after getting successful i moved to my home page. but when i change the code and put to catch login error 001 for unsuccessful login than it dont work shall i have to use jsontoken if yes please tel me that procedure

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following tutorial which has definitely helped me implement the correct login and registration screens using these resources:

Material Design
Shared Preferences
PHP scripts
MySQL Database
SQLlite Database

This is the [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) to the tutorial.
I know this is extremely late but I hope it can help you.